# Colors in debug console

Tags: c#, console, debugging

Looking at this LINQ demo:

[LINQ Framework Overview](http://www.microsoft.com/emea/msdn/spotlight/sessionh.aspx?videoid=716)

When going in debug mode, the output have colors in it. I'm using the same ObjectDumper class and I only have the black/white console window.

How can I have the same results in the console window?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What about :

```
 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
 Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
 Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

Comment: Did you look at the video, his fieldnames are one color and the values in the fields are an other, I don't beleive he switchs back and forth all the time, hmmm very good question indeed.

Comment: This works for the console but not the debug output window.

Answer (score 0):

You can set colors of the console text and/or background in the properties if that's what you're looking for... 
Just right click the title bar, click Properties and choose desired colors.

Comment: The output have different colors in it.
Name=Mr. Brownstone

Name= is in blue
Mr. Brownstone is in green...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control this programmatically, use the `System.Console.ForegroundColor` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Daok have what you want...

But you can always use Win32 calls.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] public static extern bool SetConsoleTextAttribute(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, int wAttributes);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(uint nStdHandle);
```